# wordpress site working locally but not from the domain

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, dns, wamp

My wordpress site is working locally in my wamp server, this is hosted on an ec2 instance and domain is maintained in Route 53\cloudfare. The domain is working when i checked it using mxtoolbox. The site was working and live till the time i changed my host file in the server. I removed the host file entries accidentally thinking it is a dev site, however i restored it but still the site is not working and i am getting only the "TOO MANY REDIRECTS" error.  The following is the current windows host file details

```
#
127.0.0.1 localhost
::1 localhost

127.0.0.1 mydomain.com
::1 mydomain.com
```

I restarted the server and WAMP multiple times but it is not working.

The following is my virtualhost configuration

```
# Virtual Hosts
#

<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride all
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>


#
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/sitefolder"
    <Directory  "c:/wamp/www/sitefolder/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.mydomain.com
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/sitefolder"
    <Directory  "c:/wamp/www/sitefolder/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Clean your cache and browser history first, then try doing it below:

Open your wordpress admin panel --> Settings--> General --> Make sure it points to the correct domain. --> Save

---

Or go to the wp-config.php file (Try this if the first method fails / can't be accessed)
add:

`define('WP_HOME','http://YourDomain.com');`

`define('WP_SITEURL','http://YourDomain.com');`

or
Try to remove or rename default .htaccess

---

or
Try to disable the plugin (renaming the plugin folder in the "wp-content/plugin/plugin-folder-name"  will non-active that plugin. This might solve the problem if the constraints are due to the plugin)

That's a number of ways when I resolve the ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS problem. Goodluck

Comment: I removed the .htaccess file and it started working. Thank you for your answer.